# Power BI - Edit Interaction - 'No Impact' icon not present on all visualizations

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI, I am try to control the interaction one of my slicers has with the rest of the dashboard. The strange thing is that not every type of visualization has a 'No Impact' icon.

[image]

Here's a screenshot from my own dashboard, to show you what I mean -

[image]

Notice that only the big sized numbers have the 'no-impact icon'. The smaller numbers below don't have these 'no-impact icons'. But they both are the same type of visualization (they're both Cards).

Why is this so? And is there a way to make these 'no-impact icons' reappear for the Cards that don't show them?

Thanks a lot in advance for an inputs.

Comment: Lots of overlapping stuff here. Does it show up if you spread them out?

Comment: No it doesn't. I spread them all out and tried. Some have them, some don't. All the 'arrow' cards don't. And some 'number' cards have them and some don't.

Comment: Does the slicer actually affect all of the cards?

Comment: Yes the slicer affects all cards.

Comment: Power BI Desktop or web browser? If Desktop, what build?

Comment: I have Power BI Desktop. Version: 2.66.5376.2521 64-bit (February 2019)

Answer (score 1):

To the see the "no impact" icon just increase the width of the card.